# Polymorphic association gone bad?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am working on a self-learning project for learning Rails that can be found on github [here](https://github.com/stefioan/imageT). (The latest commit includes this error)

However I am posting here all codes:

Model: photo_post.rb

```
class PhotoPost < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
has_attached_file :image, styles: {
post: "200x200>"
}
end
```

Controller: PostsController

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end
end
```

Controller: PhotoPostsController

```
class PhotoPostsController < ApplicationController
def create
content = build_content
post = current_user.posts.build(content: content)
    if post.save
        redirect_to root_path
    else
        flash.alert = "Please enter a title"
        redirect_to root_path
    end
end

private

def build_content
    PhotoPost.new(photo_post_parameters)
end

def photo_post_parameters
    params.require(:photo_post).permit(:image)
end
end
```

_post.html.erb

```
<%= div_for post do %>
<%= link_to post.user.username, post.user %>
suggested
<%= render post.content %>
<%= link_to time_ago_in_words(post.created_at), post %>
```

home_controller.rb

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
protect_from_forgery

def show
    @title_post = TitlePost.new
    @photo_post = PhotoPost.new
    @posts = current_user.posts
end
end
```

I created three models. Posts is the main one and TitlePosts and PhotoPosts are models under Posts.
The Title Posts work fine as I can submit a title.
For Photo Posts I used paperclip. However I try to upload an image I get the following error:

```
'nil' is not an ActiveModel-compatible object that returns a valid partial path.
```

You can also check the error on imageshack [here](http://img191.imageshack.us/img191/9770/0bpp.png).(Screenshot with better_errors).
I was going to copy the relevant codes and files but the full project can be found on github at the link I provided. If you need any further info please ask me.

Thank you.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please post the code in your question, not as links. Nobody has time to read your entire source code base, and external resources can change, meaning this question, in isolation, is meaningless.

Comment: @tadman I see, you are absolutely right. I will fully edit this and make it appropriate. Thanks

Comment: That's much better. Questions on Stack Overflow stick around for a long time as a resource for others who have the same sorts of problems. This helps a lot.

Comment: If you see the screenshot it is given you the answer. The post has not a content_id (is nil) so <%= render post.content%> does not know what to render

Comment: @Aguardientico Yes I thought of that and I thought is some kind of db association or belongs_to. However I am new in rails and I am not sure what is wrong... :|

Comment: Maybe a validation does not allow the PhotoPost save. You should try to remove the record from database and give a try again.

Comment: @Aguardientico still same problem. I think there are two problems. One for content_id which is nil and one is the invalid partial path

Comment: See in logs (what parameters are comming from the call. Then run a console `rails c` and try to run the same steps that you are doing in the controller. Maybe that can give you a clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK this seems weird (to me). The error was caused by forgetting to install ImageMagick.

After installing it everything works fine.

Comment: Glad you found your solution.

Answer (score 1):

In just hitting the page current_user isn't defined, so current_user.posts is trying to get posts on a Nil object.

This cleared up the error, though it isn't going to correct your issues:

HomeController ~ line 7

```
@posts = []
if current_user
  @posts = current_user.posts
end
```

You may also want to add something to your controller to require authentication so that current_user is set:

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!
```

Comment: I am logged in and this problem still exists. Also when I debug, current_user is not empty.

Comment: I also needed to move the devise_for before resources :users or I Was getting: Couldn't find User with id=sign_up

Comment: so it works for you? I am getting the same error. I did what you suggested

Comment: Changing this <%= post.content %> by removing render resolves the error, though I'm not sure what you are looking to do. post.content is Nil. 'render' is trying to take a partial path to render... so, hence nil (post.content) isn't returning a path to be rendered. Also, adding in <%= post.content_type %> shows that you are creating TitlePosts and PhotoPosts.

Comment: if I remove the render I get shown this "#<TitlePost:0x51de090>" which is the object and not the text. It was suppose to read the partial from either _title_post.html.erb if is a TitlePost or from _photo_post.html.erb if it is a PhotoPost.

Comment: This: <%= render "#{post.content_type.underscore}s/#{post.content_type.underscore}" %> in place of <%= render post.content %> gets you the effect you are looking for, but _photo_post.html.erb has then another error (undefined method `image' for nil:NilClass). Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the help Michael. Really appreciated your effort!